# What is the best C# Data Structure(s) For the Following Situation

Tags: c#, data-structures

The requirements for my application are as follows. I need to store orders which look like this:

- Each order pertains to a specific stockcode(string) and has a price, volume and whether or not it is being bought or sold(boolean) associated with it.
- I need to do several operations on all orders that pertain to a specific stock, for example get the sum of the volume of orders for stockcode "abc".
- I need to be able to add an order to the data structure
- I need to be able to remove an order from the data structure
- I need to be able to find out which order is offering the best price after an order is added or removed.

Here is what I am thinking so far:

```
public class Order : IComparable
{

   private string _StockCode;
   private bool _BidSide;
   private int _Volume;
   private decimal _Price;
   private int _ExchangeOrderId;

   public int CompareTo(Order other)
   {
        if (_BidSide != other.BidSide)
        {
            return _BidSide ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return decimal.Compare(_Price, other.Price);
   }
}
```

And then I would store the orders in a  Dictionary<string, List<Order>>. Where each stock code would be a key in the dictionary pointing to a list of orders for that stock.   I would also maintain Dictionary matching an order id to a stock code.

- For adding a new order, I simply find the appropriate list of orders in the dictionary based on the current stock code, and insert the order. I would also add an entry in the orderstock dictionary matching the current order with the approrpriate list.
- For finding the best price, I look up the order list in the dictionary for the current stock code, sort the list and print out the highest order.
- Removing is tricky. I would first need to look up the appropriate list by stock code. I would then need to iterate through all the orders for that stock code and find the one that matches the current order id and remove it. This is obviously inefficient if there are a lot of orders for the current stock code. Is this the best way of storing this information?

Comment: Something stupid, but the standards says that after _ goes lowercase.

Comment: "This is obviously inefficient if there are a lot of orders for the current stock code." Yes and no. It depends on what "a lot" is and how often you expect to delete an order. If you're deleting hundreds of orders a second and you can have 1,000 orders per stock, then it's going to be slow. But if you're talking dozens of orders for a stock and deleting an order is infrequent, then the "inefficiency" is not a problem.

Comment: Any reason this isn't in a database? They're tailor made for just this sort of behavior...

Comment: Do you need to have everything in memory at once? A relational database is the usual tool used for "average" systems like this.

Comment: +1 the question because you spelled out what you need quite clearly, explained your thoughts well, and provided some code. :) Good question!

Comment: Ultimately you are not looking for "A" data structure.  It's a system of data structures, you're looking for an application structure to some degee it seems to me.  Which is fine.  Just to make the point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to do this with a lot of data, put it in a database. This is not something you want to do in a class.

However, if you are using a small set of data, you could do this in code using LINQ.

I think you should make Order implement `IEnumerable` and then use a `List<Order>` to store your orders. Make `StockCode` a public property on the `Order` and then you can retrieve orders by using Linq:

```
List<Order> orders = GetOrderList();

var ibmOrders = from o in orders
    where o.StockCode == "IBM"
    select o;
```

Removing items from the list is quite simple:

```
List<Order> orders = GetOrderList();

var orderToRemove = (from o in orders
  where o.ExchangeId == 1315
  select o).FirstOrDefault();

if (orderToRemove != null) {
    orders.Remove(orderToRemove);
}
```

Finding by best price using Linq is quite nice:

```
Order bestPricedOrder = (from o in orders 
        orderby Price 
        select o).FirstOrDefault();
```

For more great LINQ tricks, see [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Comment: Min/max in Linq is all O(n).  If there are a fair number of objects, frequent access etc. it's not an efficient option.  It's also not really any better than the OPs suggestion.  Also, `Order` is singular from my reading of the OP.  You'd need to make a new class for the collection of orders.  OP used List.  Add/remove to the list of orders will also be far worse than the `Dictionary` adding/removing.

Comment: Good thoughts Servy. I didn't see how many objects the OP was planning to use so I thought LINQ would be a suggestion for small sets of data.  

I also think that LINQ would lead to much more readable code (read: maintainable) and so would be a better solution than the original approach.

Comment: All of the data structures the OP used implement `IEnumerable`, so you can still use LINQ.  Your code adds no improvement in that regard.  Also, if someone asks, "is there a more performant way to do this" and you think performance isn't an issue, just say so and let them do whatever rather than suggesting something noticeably less performant.  I agree performance may not be an issue, but if OP says it is I'll answer accordingly even if I question the validity.

Comment: The best way doesn't always mean the most performant way. That's why interpreted languages are all the rage these days. Sometimes the best way is the easiest to read and maintain. By the way, I didn't rewrite the Orders class, I just showed how the OP could use LINQ to accomplish what he was looking for. I'm not sure why you are saying "my code adds no improvement in that regard" and then suggesting he could still use LINQ.

Comment: The OP's code treated `Order` as a single value, not a number of values.  He then had a `List` of `Order`s representing the groups that your `Order` class represents and had a `Dictionary` to collect all of those (you used `List`). `Dictionary` and `List` both implement `IEnumerable` so any Linq query that could be executed on your data structure could be executed on the OPs (or mine).  Several of the operations the OP has said are the most common could be done more effectively using non-LINQ methods of those classes.  In particular adding, removing, finding min/max, and searching.

Comment: Tell you what, why don't you provide a query that your implementation would be able to perform using LINQ that either Mine or the OPs wouldn't.  Bonus points if yours would be any more readable or perform quicker.

Comment: Servy, put away the sword. You need to relax a bit. :) I personally believe LINQ is more readable and I love to use it in limited situations. I'm not claiming my code does something yours doesn't. I'm also not claiming it cures cancer or allows you to levitate on Tuesdays. Thanks for the vigorous debate. And remember, we're all on here trying to help other developers out.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an additional dictionary, which consists of key = orderid, value = reference to order in the list in the initial dictionary of stock codes.

This will act like an index and give you constant time deletion. Assuming you Order ID is distinct it will map 1:1. Just make sure you delete it from both dictionaries.

As suggested in comments I would recommend an additional dictionary of the computed sums that you need accessible by stock code.  This is trading off constant time access for memory.  Unless memory is an issue this would seem favourable to calculating it every time you need it.
If you get a new order in you can just update the sums, averages, etc.  Just keep in mind if you are doing stuff in parallel you'll need some locking to ensure you don't have issues.

Comment: PS to OP, Cool name Fonzie ;)

Comment: In the same flavor, I would add a class that described the state of the bids to cache average, highest bid, etc - which would be updated with each removal/addition of bids, and would store the list of current bids. This way, your updating could be a LOT faster. All the other suggestions for going to a database add value but complexity, besides using PLINQ on in-memory enumerables you can get incredible performance.

Comment: @payo Caching best price for the whole deal wouldn't be bad, but caching best price for each code would add up pretty fast, and not buy nearly as much in terms of added benefit.  I'd avoid it unless there was compelling profiler evidence it helped.

Comment: Yup absolutely I would store these things in a cache class :)  Good point! +1 I agree with you on the database point, see my comment to Servy ;)  It's obviously a bit tongue-in-cheek but w/e

Comment: @Servy sure, it could argued either way. I agree profiling would be VERY valuable.

Comment: @Servy As with anything else of course it'll depend on usage.  Akin to whether or not to store a calculated field in a database. Or how much to denormalize etc.

Comment: @payo I'd be *very* surprised to see caching be of benefit here.  That's why I brought up profiling.  I'd be confident it's not worthwhile without solid proof.  Especially if you used a SortedSet as I suggested, because getting that derived data is so quick/easy that way you're saving so very little.

Comment: @Servy I'd say it would be a matter of access time vs memory.  One is going to be constant one isn't.  
If the OP is handling a lot of parallel operations on an in memory set I'd say that even the small savings of additional cache at the expense of memory could be worth it, but again depends on the OPs usage.  You're spot on with the point of profiling though.  No point in doing all that "optimization" (If you consider access speed vs memory an optimization even, again needs dependent) until you know if you have a problem.

Comment: Also @payo
"I need to be able to find out which order is offering the best price after an order is added or removed."
This of course can be stored in a class as well as
"I need to do several operations on all orders that pertain to a specific stock, for example get the sum of the volume of orders for stockcode "abc"."
So a dictionary of sums(and the like) for a given Stock code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that a database would be the best option; they are designed for this type of thing.

If you needed to hold onto this data in memory, and there really are a lot of Orders per code, then I'd go with a `Dictionary<string, SortedSet<Order>>`.  The SortedSet will make finding the min/max easy, as well as quick insertion/removal.

Comment: Databases are the way to go if you need persistence, transactions, and things like this.  An in memory solution can be quite fast (obviously) and ideal depending on the needs of the OP (Which I grant I too would assume require persistence and transactions ;) )
Perhaps the OP just plans on never turning off the computer or having it crash ;)  Including hot memory swaps for when the data gets too large :D

Comment: I suppose as an example one could look at asp.net sessions.  
They support an in memory set, a state server, AND a database option depending on your needs.